# Can you grow anything edible in leaf mold while it's decomposing?

Tags: compost

I have hundreds of gallons of leafs that I've mulched with a WORX leaf mulcher. They're in one large bin now. I'm wanting to know *before* I move this soil to a raised bed, is there anything that you can grow in them **while** they're decomposing into soil?

As a leaf compost, can I put potatoes in them? Or some for of edible mushroom?

Answer (score 1):

You could experiment with mushroom inoculation, indeed. As long as your pile is humid and kept in shade, they should grow. I would read up a little on what would the best mushroom type be for that medium, but oyster mushrooms seem to be versatile.

Good luck, let us know how it goes!

Answer (score 1):

My grandparents grew pumpkins in the compost pile. The pile consisted of (somewhat aged - there was a pre-compost pile too)pig manure, chicken manure, hay and greens. It sounds absurd to me now but you should at least research the opportunity. Also nice is that the fruits(pumpkins) are created at a distance from the root - so not onto the pile.

I don't think they added any soil to the pile but I was too little a kid to remember correctly.

As a second option, look into acid-loving plants. Composts are supposed to be quite acidic.